# Mean Vector of Cluster

Tags: python, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis

I am trying to calculate the mean vector of each cluster. I want to get a method that is much faster than O(n^2). What should I change to make it more efficient?

```
def compute_means(self,clusters,documents)
    noc=defaultdict(lambda:0) #number of clusters
    soc=defaultdict(lambda:Counter()) # sum of clusters
    avg=[] #used for average

    for c in clusters:
        d_ID,c_ID,dist=c
        soc[c_ID] += documents[d_ID]
        noc[c_ID] += 1

    for FFCID in sorted(soc.keys()): #Cluster ID, also reference to CID from final fantasy
        total_n=float(noc[FFCID])
        for k in soc[FFCID].keys(): #keys
            soc[FFCID][k]=soc[FFCID][k]/total_n
    avg.append(soc[FFCID])

    print [item[1] for item in sorted(noc.items())]
    return avg
```

Comment: may be you use k-mean clustering technique. so for  more efficient you can try another clustering algorithm

Comment: This is O(n) not O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

Computing the mean of a set usually scales only O(n.d)
I.e. linear in size and dimensionality.

If this is too slow, you will need to optimize your code better. Avoid all the fancy stuff like hashmaps and lambdas where possible. Some of these operations come with a hidden (but real) price tag.

When working with slow interpreter languages like Python and R, try to use "vectorized" operations where possible. Using these, you can delegate the heavy lifting to fast C and Fortran code from the libraries and you'll end up with even less own code!